# How to open my iOS app from Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios9, bots, facebook-chat

I am building one of the FB Messenger Bot applications and i want to send my apps customer URL into messenger so that user can tap on it to open the app (The app is already installed on the device). This is app is not in the app store and just a demo for now.

How can i achieve this ? When i am sending customeURL:// as text back to messenger it identifies it as bad URL.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you found any solution for you this question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some text before and after your URL?